# Confusion about Models in Backbone + React application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Here's an [example](https://github.com/shaohua/todomvc-react-flux-backbone/blob/master/js/stores/TodoStore.js) that uses Backbone with React.

He defines a `Model`: `var _todos = new Backbone.Model();`

And then adds two functions to it:

```
var TodoStore = _.extend(_todos, {
  areAllComplete: function() {
    return _.every(_todos.keys(), function(id){
      return _todos.get(id).complete;
    });
  },
  getAll: function() {
    return _todos.toJSON();
  }
});
```

What I don't understand is why `areAllComplete` is being applied to a `Model` instead of to a `Collection`.

Shouldn't this be a function in a `Collection` that will get all of its models and check that `complete` attribute.

Similarly, I would expect `getAll` to belong to a `Collection` - get all of its models.

This example seems to replace `Collection` with `Model`.

Maybe I don't totally understand how models are used.

Comment: I don't understand why you would mix Backbone and Flux.

Comment: Re:model v collection, it depends on how you store them on the server. It appears here that the model is in fact a _list_ of todos, which each item just being keyed as an attribute on that model. The whole thing seems pretty goofy to me.

Comment: @Mathletics    is there a reason why I shouldn't use the two together? React is just the "V in MVC", right? I want to use Backbone for routing and Stores. I've been considering this [approach](http://www.toptal.com/front-end/simple-data-flow-in-react-applications-using-flux-and-backbone).

Comment: I responded with React in mind. Is that what you meant? Or why am I using, specifically, Flux architecture with Backbone?

Comment: I meant what I said; I don't understand mixing Flux with Backbone. Backbone already handles data storage and events. (Though I will admit I'm not well-versed in Flux.)

Comment: I was already planning on using React and decided to use Backbone for the stores and routing. Flux I'm using because I like the design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example is using `Backbone.Model` in a fairly wierd way in my opinion.

[This](https://github.com/shaohua/todomvc-react-flux-backbone/blob/master/js/stores/TodoStore.js#L37-L43) is where it's adding new todos to the store:

```
var id = Date.now();
  _todos.set(id, {
    id: id,
    complete: false,
    text: text
  });
}
```

What it's basically doing is setting every todo-item as an attribute of the `Model`, using the id as the attribute name. It ends up with `_todos.attributes` looking something like below

```
{
  "1436600629317": {
    "id": 1436600629317,
    "complete": false,
    "text": "foo"
  },
  "1436600629706": {
    "id": 1436600629706,
    "complete": false,
    "text": "bar"
  }
}
```

That's the same output you get from `_todos.toJSON()`. I've no idea why they decided to implement it like that, if they were to try using Backbone.Sync they'd end up with a server API that's not exactly RESTful. It seems strange to use Backbone without leveraging any of the things Backbone provides. There's a reference to the `change` event [here](https://github.com/shaohua/todomvc-react-flux-backbone/blob/master/js/stores/TodoStore.js#L25) but I don't see it being used anywhere. You could easily reimplement that store using any regular JS object.

The only thing that example seem to be actually using from Backbone is `Backbone.Events` in the dispatcher. You're totally right that using a Collection would make way more sense because then you could actually make it talk to a REST based server API. That example seems to only use Backbone for the sake of using Backbone.